# WPF real-time application users data preview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, real-time, inotifypropertychanged

Im developing wpf application for real-time socket data reading and data displaying from several Heart-Rate devices identified by its MAC addresses. The devices identification, current beat per minute value and other device data are stored in a list updated each time, when new value comes:

public static List listClients = new List();

I can make an observable collection and display data of all devices real-time in a ListView.

What I need is to have a list of users, when each user can have none / one or more devices paired. The listview should then show data of selected users and values of paired devices (heart beats) in real-time. The users and users to clients relations (pairing) can be stored in a database. But I don't know, how to create binding to show data real-time based on users to devices relation.

Thank you,
Jan Kijonka

Comment: This is not a programming service, if you show what you have tried, we can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.